# Symfony2 MopaBootstrap - exception in BootstrapSandbox CSS

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the `MopaBootstrapSandbox` demo up and running on my Win 7 / Xampp installation.  I can see the main demo page but it isn't styled.  When I look at the stylesheet I see the following exception in it ... this isn't whole of the exception as its interleaved with the css.

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Exception
[message] expected color value: failed at `color: darken(@grayLight, 10%); }` line: 33
[1] Exception: expected color value: failed at `color: darken(@grayLight, 10%); }`
```

line: 33

```
at n/a
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 3258

at lessc_parser-&gt;throwError(&#039;expected color value&#039;, &#039;399&#039;)
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 1862

at lessc-&gt;throwError(&#039;expected color value&#039;)
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 1070

at lessc-&gt;assertColor(array(&#039;keyword&#039;, &#039;&#039;))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 919

at lessc-&gt;colorArgs(array(&#039;list&#039;, &#039;,&#039;, array(array(&#039;keyword&#039;, &#039;&#039;), array(&#039;number&#039;, &#039;10&#039;, &#039;%&#039;))))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 926

at lessc-&gt;lib_darken(array(&#039;list&#039;, &#039;,&#039;, array(array(&#039;keyword&#039;, &#039;&#039;), array(&#039;number&#039;, &#039;10&#039;, &#039;%&#039;))), object(lessc))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(array(object(lessc), &#039;lib_darken&#039;), array(&#039;list&#039;, &#039;,&#039;, array(array(&#039;keyword&#039;, &#039;&#039;), array(&#039;number&#039;, &#039;10&#039;, &#039;%&#039;))), object(lessc))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 1275

at lessc-&gt;reduce(array(&#039;function&#039;, &#039;darken&#039;, array(&#039;list&#039;, &#039;,&#039;, array(array(&#039;variable&#039;, &#039;@grayLight&#039;), array(&#039;number&#039;, &#039;10&#039;, &#039;%&#039;)))))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 617

at lessc-&gt;compileProp(array(&#039;assign&#039;, &#039;color&#039;, array(&#039;function&#039;, &#039;darken&#039;, array(&#039;list&#039;, &#039;,&#039;, array(array(&#039;variable&#039;, &#039;@grayLight&#039;), array(&#039;number&#039;, &#039;10&#039;, &#039;%&#039;)))), &#039;399&#039;), object(stdClass), object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 277

at lessc-&gt;compileProps(object(stdClass), object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 215

at lessc-&gt;compileCSSBlock(object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 189

at lessc-&gt;compileBlock(object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 622

at lessc-&gt;compileProp(array(&#039;block&#039;, object(stdClass), &#039;431&#039;), object(stdClass), object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 277

at lessc-&gt;compileProps(object(stdClass), object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 271

at lessc-&gt;compileRoot(object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 186

at lessc-&gt;compileBlock(object(stdClass))
    in C:\xampp\htdocs\T1\vendor\leafo\lessphp\lessc.inc.php line 1663

at lessc-&gt;compile(&#039;//
```

Here's the composer.json (part)

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "master",
    "twitter/bootstrap": "2.3.1",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master",
    "leafo/lessphp": "0.3.9",
    "liip/theme-bundle": "dev-Versionfix as master",
},

   "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [ ... 
        "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [ ...
        "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
    ]
},
```

To be honest I'm quite new to Symfony 2 so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this helps you or not but, leafo/lessphp may be the issue.. I was having a similar problem with the less files compiling and found that leafo is not being updated on a regular basis..  ([Forum post](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/520))
You can easily change from leafo to the more stable distribution ([oyejorge/less.php](https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php))

change you composer.phar file to:

```
"oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5",
```

run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will remove lefo and install oyejorge
Change you config.yml file to:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: ".less$"
            # Formatter options: compressed, lessjs, classic
            formatter: "compressed"
            preserve_comments: false
```

if you want to you can change the filter name to `less` instead of `lessphp`.